# Using a template to create arrays of varying length inside of class in C++11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Say I have a class:

```
template <int S1>
class Cont {
    private:
       std::array<int, S1> nums;
    public:
       Cont(std::array<int, S1> ns);
}
```

When trying to link my program, I am getting an error saying that, for example, Cont(std::array ns) is undefined. So am I doing something wrong? Or will this never work due to how arrays work?

EDIT: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the constructor is defined. I was only giving the header to illustrate what I meant.

Comment: Um, did you define the constructor or not?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: It might help to _also_ give a) a definition and b) an instantiation, such that all together it is a complete failing example.

Comment: Looking at what Brian linked I think the problem is that I never instantiated. Once I get back to my desk I will try it out

Comment: Please give the exact error.

Comment: @davidbak the problem was that I hadn't instantiated the template. Thanks for the link.

Comment: potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Answer (score 3):

```
Cont(std::array<int, S1> ns)
```

Is only a declaration, you need to define it as well.

like:

```
Cont(std::array<int, S1> ns){
    // code
}
```